# stable_baselines3 callback on each step

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am training a `stable_baselines3` `PPO` agent and want to perform some task on every step. To do this, I'm using a callback `CustomCallback` with `_on_step` method defined.

But it appears that `_on_step` is called only on every `PPO.n_steps`, so if `n_steps` param is `1024`, then `CustomCallback._on_step` appears to be called only on every `1024` steps.

How can you do something on every `1` step, insted of on every `PPO.n_steps` steps?

```
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_vec_env
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import BaseCallback

class CustomCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, freq, verbose=0):
        super().__init__(verbose)
        self.freq = freq

    def _on_step(self):
        if self.n_calls % self.freq == 0:
            print('do something')
        return True

env = make_vec_env("CartPole-v1", n_envs=1)
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, n_steps=1024)
model.learn(
    total_timesteps=25000,
    callback=CustomCallback(freq=123),
)
```